# How to create an algorithm for matchmaking using jetpack compose and MongoDb?

Tags: android, mongodb, matchmaking

I am trying to learn how to create a matchmaking algorithm. Just the general part of matching individuals with eachother. Lets say I have 5 individuals and I want to match 2 individuals that share 3 of the same interests/Caracteristics or relatively close to one and another (ex. Length, haircolor and favourite food). How would I go about doing so? Any suggestions to articles that can give me some insight? I will be doing this using compose and mongoDb

Appreciate any feedback!